# Google chrome console shows different value for same same string with slash

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Textbox With Slash</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="textbox" id="regex"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="f1()" value="Add"/>
        <script>
            function f1() {
                let regexDOM = document.getElementById("regex")
                document.regex = {
                    enabled: true,
                    regex: regexDOM.value
                }
                console.log(document.regex)
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the following screenshot shows the console output.
My question is why in the console output in line-1 there is double-slash while triple slash in line-3?

[image]

Comment: The first line formats the string with outer single-quote characters. The second uses double-quote characters, so three backslash characters are needed: two for the actual backslash, one for the embedded double-quote. The console shows strings like that to make them easier to cut/paste into code.

Comment: Also the `type` should be "text", not "textbox", if you really want it to be correct. The "textbox" value will be ignored and it will default to "text", but you might as well take it out entirely.